# Huawei Analytics console export data failure

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Tried to export data on below dates and i got error saying "Failure details".
why this export data could fail? Do we have any limit for data exporting?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The data volume is limited, select a date range in the upper right corner, and we can view data in a preset time range (such as Last 7 days) or a custom time range.

Please follow the link for viewing analytics data:  https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-view_analysis.